# BackgroundWorker not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a background worker because some method in my program need time for download the data from internet. This method "block" for 5-6 second the software, so I want use the background worker to execute the method like a thread. In my class I've create this:

```
 private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

after, in ComboBox selection changed, I call the BackgroundWorker in this way:

```
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(doWork);
```

the doWork method contains:

```
public void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        classifica.getClassifica(); //call the method from another class
}
```

now my problem is that the method `doWork` isn't called by the BackgroundWorker.
What I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you start it? Besides, you don't need BackgroundWorker to run something in the background. The preferred way is to use `async/await` to create an asynchronous event handler.

Comment: calling worker.DoWork does not start automatically?

Comment: No you need to call `RunWorkerAsync` on the worker object

Comment: First, you don't call it anywhere. Second, no, `DoWork` is the event handler.  You need to call `RunWorkerAsync` to start it

Comment: The only problem is that the method is executed but the DataGrid is not populated. Probably the backgroudn worker cause this bug?

Comment: You're probably trying to update the UI from DoWork rather than RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: I need maybe the Dispatcher? How to use it? Can you show me, please?

Comment: The RunWorkerCompleted event does all that for you, you don't need to dispatch anything. There are lots of basic tutorials online for BackGroundWorker with complete code samples, have you tried any of these?

Comment: Nope, can you show me some tutorial to populate datagrid when use a background worker please?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean to you, but can't you type "c# backgroundworker datagridview" into Google by yourself? It doesn't seem like you've tried much. Anyway, all you need to do is stick any UI updating code in either ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted event as you would in any other part of your program and the rest is done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
if (worker.IsBusy != true)
{
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Although unless you're set on a BackGroundWorker or can't target .NET 4.5 then I highly recommend [WebClient.DownloadDataAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144190%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Use it like this:

```
static void DownloadData()
{
    string url = "http://google.com";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;
    client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));
}

static void DownloadDataCompleted(object sender,
DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle returned data here
}
```

Does all this for you without using anything else. Simple!

Answer (score 2):

You have to start the worker.

```
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `worker.RunWorkerAsync();` to start the worker.
There is also an overload to allow you to pass an `object` parameter to your `DoWork` function:

```
void RunWorkerAsync(object argument)
```

You can also add a handler so you will know when the worker is done: `worker.RunWorkerCompleted`.  In this handler you can access the DataGrid because it will be in the UI thread (assuming you created the worker in the UI thread)

Comment: I've executed worker.RunWorkerAsync() but the method was not executed.

Comment: Are you calling it after adding the `DoWork` handler?

Comment: Also @HaroldFinch , make sure the main program isn't exiting before the handler gets a chance to execute.

Comment: I need to populate the DataGrid so I need to call the thread of the GUI. How to do this?

Comment: @HaroldFinch - you need to add a handler so you will know when the worker is done: `worker.RunWorkerCompleted`.  In this handler you can access the DataGrid because it will be in the UI thread (assuming you created the worker in the UI thread)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the background worker this way

```
if (bw.IsBusy != true)
{
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Follow this for more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx